# Unknown error code during application install “-24” installing Instapaper

Tags: nexus-7

I'm getting the following error when I attempt to install Instapaper through the Play store

```
Unknown error code during application install “-24”
```

Googling suggests I need to delete any remnants in the `/data/data` instapaper folder.  Unfortunately, that seems impossible, I've tried both using file explorers on the device, and adb shell, which tells me "Permission denied" when I try and `ls` the `/data/data` folder's contents.

I really don't want to perform a factory reset reinstall everything that is on my device (Nexus 7 2013).

My device is not rooted.

How can I fix things so I can install this app?

I have a logcat file I can attach if it would be helpful.

Comment: Have you installed Instapaper on the same device before?

Comment: Not that I recall, it is installed on another android device. Maybe something came across because they use the same Google account?

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue. Maybe it's something else, but I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

You would need root to access `/data/data`, and rooting would require unlocking your bootloader, which would wipe your data.

Other than doing a Factory Reset, there may be no other way.

Comment: imho, that's a horrible design flaw by Google.  I should at the very least with adb shell be able to get into the `/data` folder to fix issues without a hardware reset.  I can't imagine having to reinstall windows because an app had a botched install.